# How to boldify math without changing font style

Tags: math-mode

I want to boldify math equations and symbols with out changing the actual font.

I tried the following, but I am not getting satisfactory results.

```
      a=f \equiv 2 \mod 4
      \bm{a = f \equiv 2 \mod 4}
      \mathbf{a = f \equiv 2 \mod 4}
      {\boldmath $a = f \equiv 2 \mod 4$}
```

The output for the above tags is as follows

[image]

I want my equation like the third line with fully bold, but with preserved alphabet font as in line 1.

`\bm` is not boldifying the entire equation, and `\boldmath` is not boldyfying at all. How can I preserve alphabet font using `\mathbf`?

Comment: First of all: Don't use `$$....$$`. That's deprecated syntax. Use `\[...\]` instead. Second: Don't post fragments only. Third: `\boldmath` must be used outside of math mode ('must', because there's a warning!)

Comment: Third: Yeah true,  even though I use \boldmath outside math, it is not boldifying the equation.

Comment: `\bm {...}` is bold for me, as well as `\boldmath`

Comment: For me, it is working on some pages, and not working on some pages, working for some part of the equation and not working for remaining part of the equation. So, i need to know the way of using \[ \mathbf  \] without changing font.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "So, i need to know the way of using `\mathbf` without changing font"

Comment: I mean, the font style should be same as in first line, but mathbf is changing the font style of alphabets. The font style of alphabets in line 1 of the output has to be preserved.

Comment: I need to get the line 1 with fully  bold as in line 3, but the style of font must be as it is.

Comment: `So, i need to know the way of using  \mathbf` doesn't really have an answer `\mathbf` is a font changing command that changes the font of (only) letters to bold upright roman. What you want is `\bm` which will select bold for all symbols for which you have a bold font or `\boldmath` if you want the entire expression bold, again assuming you have bold math fonts. If it is not working for you, post a proper example that people can test/debug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `\bm` or `\boldmath`, not `\mathbf`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

$ a=f \equiv 2 \mod 4$

$\bm{ a=f \equiv 2 \mod 4}$

{\boldmath $ a=f \equiv 2 \mod 4$}

\end{document}
```

Of course the bold symbols need to exist, not all font sets include bold.

Comment: What causes the difference in spacing?

Comment: @Manuel `\bm` is a bold region in a math expression using the font parameters of the (non bold) `\textfont2` but `\boldmath` sets up the entire math parameters based on the fontdimens in the bold `\textfont2`

Answer (score 3):

For me, there's no difference between `\bm` and `\boldmath` regarding the regular symbols and numbers, `\mathbf` switches the font indeed and the spacing is different:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\mathcontent}{%
  a=f \equiv 2 \mod 4%
}

\begin{document}
\[ a=f \equiv 2 \mod 4\]
\[\bm{a = f \equiv 2 \mod 4}\]
\[\mathbf{a = f \equiv 2 \mod 4}\]
\boldmath
\[ a = f \equiv 2 \mod 4\] \unboldmath

Now all using \verb!\boldmath!

\boldmath

\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{$\mathcontent$}

\fbox{$\bm{\mathcontent}$}

\fbox{$\mathbf{\mathcontent}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]